# Renew Figure Environment Nature Documentclass

Tags: environments

I want to renew the `figure` environment because I want the caption to be `Supplementary Figure` instead of `Figure`.
I am using the `nature` documentclass and found the code snippet:

```
\renewenvironment{figure}{\let\caption\NAT@figcaption}{}
    
\newcommand{\NAT@figcaption}[2][]{\AtEndDocument{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}
    \ifthenelse{\value{figure}=1}{
        \newpage\noindent%
%        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    }{
        \par\vfill
    }
    \sffamily\noindent\textbf{Figure \arabic{figure}}\hspace{1em}#2}
    }
```

in the `nature.cls`.
My idea was to include the code

```
\renewenvironment{figure}{\let\caption\NAT@figcaption}{}
\renewcommand{\NAT@figcaption}[2][]{\AtEndDocument{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}
    \ifthenelse{\value{figure}=1}{
        \newpage\noindent%
%        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    }{
        \par\vfill
    }
    \sffamily\noindent\textbf{Supplementary Figure \arabic{figure}}\hspace{1em}#2}
    }
```

in my document but obviously, that does not work.
Is there a way to change the figure environment just for the particular document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patch works fine here:

```
\documentclass{nature}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\NAT@figcaption}[2][]{\AtEndDocument{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}
    \ifthenelse{\value{figure}=1}{
        \newpage\noindent%
%        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    }{
        \par\vfill
    }
    \sffamily\noindent\textbf{Supplementary Figure \arabic{figure}}\hspace{1em}#2}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is: "Supplementary Figure 1 A figure"

Since you have given us only code snippets instead of a complete document (MWE) it's hard to tell what you have done wrong.

Comment: I added it after ```\begin{document}```, I believe that was the error.

Comment: Nature may not appreciate your changing their custom \caption.

Comment: @JohnKormylo To my knowledge, there are no such restrictions regarding manuscripts.